# disconnect from the previous socket connection and make a new connection

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I am building an angular app which fetches real time data using sensors and node.js as backend.

```
 <div>
      <label> <b>Device: </b></label>
      <mat-form-field class="parameter">
        <mat-select  [(value)]="selectedDevice">
          <mat-option  value="00:12:4b:00:19:b8:6b:46">00:12:4b:00:19:b8:6b:46</mat-option>
          <mat-option  value="fd00::212:4b00:197b:2778">fd00::212:4b00:197b:2778</mat-option>
          <mat-option  value="fd00::212:4b00:197b:274a">fd00::212:4b00:197b:274a</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button (click)="realTime(selectedDevice)">Get Data for ID</button>
      </div>
```

```
component.ts

    realTime(id) {
      this.webSocket.connect_id(id).subscribe ((data:any) => console.log(data))

    }
```

```
in service.ts


  connect_id(id) : Observable<string>{
    this.socket = io('http://server_ip/milo/' + id, {transports : ['websocket']})
    console.log(this.socket)
    return this.observable = new Observable((observer) => {
      this.socket.on('data',(res : any) => observer.next(res));
    })
  }
```

So when i select a device from dropdown and 'Get Data for ID' , a socket connection is made and real time data is being fetched.

So now, when i selected another device from dropdown and 'Get Data for ID' again, now i get data for the devices. I want data of only the recently selected device.How do I achieve this? How do I disconnect from the previous connection?

Comment: is it possible to do it alone from the client side? or should something be added on server side too?

Comment: Well for this condition you can use "race" operator from rxjs.
This article might help you achieve it: https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511

Comment: hi @SumitVekariya , thanks for sharing the blog, with the help of it i was able to solve the problem of connection to  multiple sevres and code repetition, but my main issue is to how to stop calls from previous socket and recieve data from only new socket.Any idea about that?

Comment: Did you try with io.removeAllListeners([eventName])  ??